# Does ASP.NET MVC perform better under IIS7 versus IIS6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, migration

I'm running my ASP.NET MVC app on an IIS6 host right now, and they're not willing to upgrade my server, nor move my site to an IIS7 server - unless I purchase a new account to transfer to.

Under IIS6 I understand there are a  lot of wildcard mappings happening to get the .net framework to process the incoming connections for each type. I'm assuming this incurs quite a bit of overhead...

Does ASP.NET MVC perform better under IIS7? I don't think it's super important for my site just yet, but as it grows I'll need to consider this.

Thanks!

Comment: Has anyone benchmarked it? I for one would be <i>very</i> interested to see the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET applications (whether ASP.NET (MVC or otherwise), WCF, etc.) should run better on IIS7 because IIS7 was built with .NET in mind.

Please see [ASP.NET Integration With IIS 7.0](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis7/):

> IIS 7.0 takes ASP.NET further by
>   integrating the ASP.NET runtime
>   extensibility model with the core
>   server. This allows developers to
>   fully extend the IIS 7.0 server with
>   the richness of ASP.NET 2.0 and the
>   .NET Framework, instead of using the
>   lower level IIS C++ APIs. Existing
>   ASP.NET applications also immediately
>   benefit from tighter integration using
>   existing ASP.NET features like Forms
>   Authentication, Roles, and Output
>   Caching for all content.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably about all I needed to know. I had a hunch... :D

Answer (score 0):

I have not benchmarked the performance in the two but my experience says that Asp.net MVC is easier to configure on IIS7 than on IIS6 especially when you are on a shared hosting. The url mapping and stuff works best without complain on IIS7.

Comment: I'm wondering if IIS6 is the culprit for some random errors I'm getting where certain route variables aren't being set correctly... they work 99% of the time, but sometimes, very rarely, I get a strange error that appears as though a variable set through the route isn't being set correctly... hmm...

Answer (score 0):

I just found this http://forums.iis.net/t/1150694.aspx#1875128
saying that IIS6 is faster.

Any now with .NET 4 MVC can be auto configured to just work.